# Join csv files ased on common column in java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I want to join two csv files based on a common column in. My two csv files and final csv file looks like this.

Here are the example files - 1st file looks like:

```
 sno,first name,last name
 --------------------------    
 1,xx,yy
 2,aa,bb
```

2nd file looks like:

```
 sno,place
 -----------     
 1,pp
 2,qq
```

Output:

```
 sno,first name,last name,place
 ------------------------------     
 1,xx,yy,pp
 2,aa,bb,qq
```

Code:

```
    CSVReader r1 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("c:/csv/file1.csv"));; 
    CSVReader r2 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("c:/csv/file2.csv"));; 
    HashMap<String,String[]> dic = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

    int commonCol = 1; 
    r1.readNext(); // skip header
    String[] line = null;
    while ((line = r1.readNext()) != null)
    {
      dic.put(line[commonCol],line)
    }

    commonCol = 1; 
   r2.readNext(); 
    String[] line2 = null;
    while ((line2 = r2.readNext()) != null)
    {
      if (dic.keySet().contains(line2[commonCol])
      {
        // append line to existing entry
      }
      else
      {
         // create a new entry and pre-pend it with default values
         // for the columns of file1
      }
    }

    foreach (String[] line : dic.valueSet())
    {
       // write line to the output file.
    }
```

I don't know how to proceed further to get desired output. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: On unix there is also a `join` command that will do this, depending on what output you want for unmatched rows.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use zero as your  `commonCol` value as the first column has index zero rather than one.

```
 if (dic.keySet().contains(line2[commonCol])
  {
    //Get the whole line from the first file.
    String firstPart = dic.get(line2[commonCol]);
    //Gets the line from the second file, without the common column.
    String secondPart = String.join (Arrays.copyOfRange(line2, 1, line2.length -1), ",");
    // Join together and put in Hashmap.
    dic.put(line2[commonCol], String.join (firstPart, secondPart));
  }
  else
  {
     // create a new entry and pre-pend it with default values
     // for the columns of file1
    String firstPart = String.join(",","some", "default", "values")
    String secondPart = String.join (Arrays.copyOfRange(line2, 1, line2.length -1), ",");
    dic.put(line2[commonCol], String.join (firstPart, secondPart));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply 
i am still facing not able to compile code as there is some issue with Arrays.copyOfRange function. Can you please help